# upload image file to state with react

Tags: image, reactjs, web, upload

I am trying to upload an image with react with this code

```
<input type="file" id="InputFile" accept="image/*" value={this.state.image} onChange={this.handelChangeImage} />
```

this is the state

```
constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = {
    image: [],
}

this.handelChangeImage = this.handelChangeImage.bind(this);
```

}

and this is the binding function

```
handelChangeImage(event) {
   let image = event.target.files[0];
   let form = new FormData();
   form.append('image', image);
   this.setState({
       image: form,
   });
```

}

it gives me that error

> Uncaught DOMException: Failed to set the 'value' property on 'HTMLInputElement': This input element accepts a filename, which may only be programmatically set to the empty string.

any help!!

Comment: I'm not familiar with using FormData() to read a file into state.  If you don't mind using new FileReader instead then I could provide you with an answer.

Answer (score 3):

My error was here

```
<input type="file" id="InputFile" accept="image/*" value={this.state.image} onChange={this.handelChangeImage} />
```

I have to remove this `value={this.state.image}`

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you are not reading your file properly, try something like:

```
handelChangeImage(event) {
  const reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function(ee) {
    this.setState({fileData: ee.target.result});
  }.bind(this);
}
```

You can find more info about FileReader [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader).

Comment: That's why you cant set the value of an input with type file. Try to

`render() {
  if (this.state.fileData) {
    thumbnail = <img src={this.state.fileData} />
  }
  return thumbnail;
}`

And you should be able to see your img.